# Standard normal distribution - Area to the left or area to the right

Tags: statistics

I am reading [Understandable Statistics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Understandable_Statistics_Concepts_and_M.html?id=f925DQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y). In chapter 6, guided exercise 8, there is a question that goes like this:

> Suppose the time to complete a test is normally
>   distributed with $\mu$=40 minutes and $\sigma$=5
>   minutes. **After how many minutes can we expect
>   all but about 3% of the tests to be completed?**

I am having a hard time understanding the last sentence.

> After how many minutes can we expect all but about 3% of the tests to
>   be completed?

Do I have to look area to the left or to the right of standard normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted statement is equivalent to asking:

> In a large population of test takers, on average, how long would you need to wait in order for 97% of the tests to be completed?

Another way to phrase it:

> What is the least amount of time you could allot for a randomly selected test taker so that they have a 97% probability of finishing within that time limit?